# IntelliJ: repeat next command N times

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm a big fan of Emacs editor and my IntelliJ is configured with various key-bindings borrowed from Emacs. A lack of one particular command drives me crazy - I searched for it in key bindings, then searched for some add-on that emulates it, but without any luck.

Emacs has "repeat next command N times" command. There are several ways of "multiplying" the next command in Emacs, but the most basic one would be to prefix the command with `C-u <number>`.

For example: `C-f` command moves the cursor forward one character. The following command will move the cursor forward 5 characters:

`C-u 5 C-f`

The same `C-u <number>` prefix works for other commands as well.

So, does IntelliJ has some alternative to Emacs' "repeat next command N times" command?